# Domain Name Windows Vista Does Not Exist In The Database

Tags: installation, dotnetnuke

I am trying to install DOTNETNUKE model on my local machine ( Windows Vista) but seem to be running into a problem right after installing the Database. Not exactly sure where to go to fix the problem or what I need to do next. Anyone have any idea how I can deal with this? Thanks in advance.

```
DotNetNuke Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Domain Name Windows Vista Does Not Exist In The Database 

DotNetNuke supports multiple portals from a single database/codebase. It 
accomplishes this by converting the URL of the client browser Request to
a valid PortalID in the Portals database table. The following steps 
describe the process: 


Web Server Processing

When a web server receives a Request from a client browser, it compares the 
file name extension on the target URL resource to its Application Extension 
Mappings defined in IIS. 
Based on the corresponding match, IIS then sends the Request to the defined 
Executable Path ( aspnet_asapi.dll in the case of ASP.NET Requests ). The 
aspnet_isapi.dll engine processes the Request in an ordered series of events
beginning with Application_BeginRequest. 


HttpModule.URLRewrite OnBeginRequest ( UrlRewriteModule.vb )

The Request URL is parsed based on the "/" character 
A Domain Name is constructed using each of the relevant parsed URL segments. 

Examples: 

URL: http://www.domain.com/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com
URL: http://209.75.24.131/default.aspx = Domain Name: 209.75.24.131
URL: http://localhost/DotNetNuke/default.aspx = Domain Name: localhost/DotNetNuke
URL: http://www.domain.com/virtualdirectory/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com/virtualdirectory
URL: http://www.domain.com/directory/default.aspx = Domain Name: www.domain.com/directory


Using the Domain Name, the application queries the database ( Portals table -
PortalAlias field ) to locate a matching record. 

Note: If there are multiple URLs which correspond to the same portal then the
PortalAlias field must contain each valid Domain Name in a comma seperated list. 

Example: 

URL: http://localhost/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
URL: http://MACHINENAME/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
URL: http://209.32.134.65/DotNetNuke/default.aspx
PortalAlias: localhost/DotNetNuke,MACHINENAME/DotNetNuke,209.32.134.65/DotNetNuke 

Note: If you are installing the application to a remote server you must 
modify the PortalAlias field value for the default record in the Portals
table according to the rules defined above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell the status of your installation.   I'll assume that the database was created and populated during install.

Firstly, look at the table

```
dbo.PortalAlias
```

If your planning to run/debug on your local IIS, then you should have an entry for HTTPAlias of

```
localhost/YOURVIRTUALDIR
```

Comment: My PortalAlias Table and my Portal Table are both Empty. Is this supposed to be the case?

Comment: Empty is definitely wrong.  Are you using a SQLServer, or the express single file MDF?

Comment: I am using SQLServer Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed, it is possible that the last step, the default installation of the Portal did not execute. In a similar case, when I selected "Custom" installation, I found that this last step was missing, but didn't yield an error.

***Resolution:*** reinstall (remove everything or install to a new location, use another DB or remove this one prior to reinstalling) and select "Auto" installation for the online wizard. This works and includes the creation of the default portal. Anything automatically configured can be altered later anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be very late, but for anyone having this issue, 
I had the same issue, after I made sure that I have updated the "Portal Alias" table in db, to have a HTTP Alias (for my local host, I set it to localhost:8089 which was equal to what I had set up in IIS binding for DNN website), with the portal ID of 0 (as my portal id was 0),
I was checking to be sure I have updated web.config file with data base connection strings, but then I realized there were two points for database connection in web.config, and I was missing one of them.
So make sure to update both two connections as:

```
1) <connectionStrings>
2) <appSettings>
```

Hope this helps.